# createPortal react 18 not rendering the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-18

I'm trying to use the `createPortal` method to render an API error message in my `ErrorSnackbar` component. However, when an error occurs, the component is not rendering as expected.

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    if (error.response) {
      const errorRoot = document.getElementById('error-snackbar');
      createPortal(<ErrorSnackbar message={error.response.data.message} />, errorRoot);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

For context, I have added two DOM nodes in my `index.html` file:

```
<div id="root"></div>

<div id="error-snackbar"></div>
```

To verify if the problem lies within the `ErrorSnackbar` component, I tried adding a simple HTML tag like `<h1>But this is not also rendering</h1>` directly to the `error-snackbar` div, but even that is not rendering when an error occurs.

I believe the issue might be related to the usage of `createPortal` in the `axios` interceptor. Could someone please help me identify why the `ErrorSnackbar` component is not rendering when an error happens? Any suggestions or insights on how to make this work would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `createPortal` returns an object that you have to render https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal#createportal

Comment: "What am I doing here?"